# Find Which data structure supports this given set of operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

i need to design a data structure that supports the following operations:
Group S which has n numbers:

1. Init(A,n) - init ds given n elements = O(n)
2. insert(x) - insert element x = O(logn)
3. find_min() - return minimum element without taking it out from the structure = O(1)
4. find_max() - return maximum element without taking it out from the structure = O(1)
5. extract_min() - delete minimum element = O(logn)
6. extract_max() - delete maximum element = O(logn)

Any ideas or suggestions on how to approach this problem or how should it be implemented would be kindly appreciated

Comment: Looks like a heap to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)

Comment: You can use a min heap and a max heap, both with all the elements in them. You need pointers across, so you can find an element in the other heap if you have one in one of the heaps.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux just a heap doesn't work since a single heap can either do efficient find_min and extract_min, or efficient find_max and extract_max, but not both.

Comment: Please see [ask] and make your title more descriptive and less ambiguous. Imagine how many different questions could have this same title and figure out how to resolve that.

Comment: two heaps: min heap and max heap

Comment: Might a SortedSet be fine, as well? Of course it is restricted in the way, that it contains every element only once, which is not stated as condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be a [Min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap). [Here](https://probablydance.com/2020/08/31/on-modern-hardware-the-min-max-heap-beats-a-binary-heap/) is a nice article about it by Malte Skarupke with a C++ implementation. [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-min-max-heap) is a Java implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a heap data structure.
More specifically a binary heap.

There are 2 types of heaps basically, a min heap in which minimum value element is present at the root node and a max heap in which maximum value element is present at the root.

So, according to the constraints given, the data structure might be composite, consisting of both min heap and a max heap.
Since you need both min and max in O(1) time complexity, you will have to keep both heaps.

Also, init process that takes O(n) time complexity, this process is called heapify, or building heap from an existing array